# model.findone() no longer accept calback

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

**EXISTING OLD CODE WHICH IS NOT WORKING AS CALLBACK NOT ACCEPTED**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {
    usernameField: 'Username',
    passwordField: 'Password'
    }, 
(username, password, callback) => {
    console.log(username + ' ' + password);
    Users.findOne({Username: username}, (error, user) => {
        if (error){
            console.log(error);
            return callback(error);
        }

        if (!user) {
            console.log('incorrect username');
            return callback(null, false, {message: "Incorrect username or password."});
        }

        console.log('finished');
        return callback(null, user);
    });
}));
```

**CHANGED THE CODE TO BOTTOM WHICH WORKS**

```js
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {
        usernameField: 'Username',
        passwordField: 'Password'
    },
    (username, password, callback) => {
        console.log(username + ' ' + password);
        Users.findOne( {Username: username})
        .then( (user) => {
            if (!user) {
                console.log('incorrect username');
                return callback(null, false, {message: "incorrect username or password."});
            }

            console.log('finished');
            return callback(null, user);

        }).catch( (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            return callback(error);
        })
    }
))
```

Hi all,

I am learning full stack development now.

I am facing an error that `model.findOne` no longer accepts a callback.

Please advise how to fix.

Googled a few article but still can't fix

**EDIT**

I have tried to change the code to the below one which is working.

But as i'm still learning, im concerned that my code is incorrect in any way possible.

Would you all help to take a look and advise if my code is correct in changing from callback to promise?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You should refactor your code so it doesn't use a non-promise callback system (like `passport.use` is doing). But your question is off topic for this site, as you have working code. Asking for a review is not on topic here.